# Magento 2.2.1 Checkout page broken and Js fail to load error

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, magento2.2, jquery

I have installed Magento 2.2.1  and set up my custom theme but checkout page looks broken and consoles showing errors:

[image]

Not sure how to resolve this issue.  Need help how can this be resolved.

How can i trace it?

Comment: If you already done static content deploy then please check by enabling display error in app/bootstrap.php and rename pub/errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml and then clear cache and reload page. When you open page source of checkout page you may see error appears there. It seems some script has been broken while page load.

Comment: Yes already did

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, could you please share? I am facing the exact same problem.

Comment: @SanjayKumar  Yes ,  to resolve this issue upgraded php to 7.1X,  soap extension and did run upgrade,  and cache flush command.   that resolved my issue.

Comment: @jack Can you try to take a look into exception.log, support_report.log or nginx/php-fpm error log? There should be something there before we digging in deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from command line interface.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Did run all the commands but still showing broken  checkout page.  What could be the issue?  i did remove my custom Js  but still showing some errors.

Comment: can you tell me have you run command for locale you are using?

Comment: I have multi store so i run command for each store.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer based on what the author asks. It should just a comment before making a final answer and be more specified to what author asking.