# Magento Checkout Stuck: Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment" component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I am on Magento 2.2. When I click on proceed with checkout, the checkout page opens (where it asks for address) but the checkout-loader jig keeps on spinning. I get below error on console:

console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-03-26 02:15:40] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment" component.

Could you please suggest? FYI, I have already tried cache cleans, redeploying static content etc but that didn't help either.

I have already tried the solution posted on below link but it did not help.
[Magento 2.2.1 Checkout page broken and Js fail to load error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206856/magento-2-2-1-checkout-page-broken-and-js-fail-to-load-error/219771#219771)

Comment: Please roll back your last changes, if checkout works, Then the problem is in  your last changes.

Comment: This is the first thing that I tried. It didn't work. Weird thing is, it used to work before. So I am guessing it is more of my setup/environment issue rather than code issue.

Answer (score 4):

In case somebody gets this error when writing their own UI Components: in my case I forgot to add the dependency parameter in my JavaScript:

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (uiComponent) {     <-- See, I forgot to mention 'ko' here! :-(
    'use strict';

     // ... etc ...
```

Hope this save somebody some frustration whilst debugging. It's an incredibly vague error message.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue on cart and checkout page, In console it shows me "Failed to load the component" error. I have research more about this and check with disable all third party modules and theme but no luck.

[image]

So, I have checked with comment out app/etc/env.php to env_bck.php file and run URL from browser address bar. I have check "Readiness Check" and found some PHP extension is missing.

[image]

I hvae installed missing PHP extension and checked site it is working fine.

This solution might be help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason this could happen is the checkoutConfig array in javascript is empty. Check the value of checkoutConfig in the browser console. If its an empty array, json_encode returned false on the backend.

In my case it was probably because of some non-utf8 friendly character in there somewhere. I ended up uploading the database again and it worked.

Edit: This was acknowledged by Magento 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17934

Seems to be an issue with different crypt keys, which can malform encrypted data and prevent json_encode from being able to parse non-utf8 characters.

Comment: Using the correct encryption key in env.php did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when logged in as a customer:

I have had the same issue. This was caused (in my case) by edits made to the checkout pages, settings, layouts etc. Why this made my checkout from stopping to work, is still something that keeps me wondering. What fixed this for me was **creating a new user** when I was done editing the checkout pages and settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am actually not overriding the default checkout module. I tried adding a new user but the issue still persists.

Comment: Try removing the front end folder from the static folder in /pub/static. After that run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing these folders manually but it didn't help. :(

Comment: Hmmm well my guesses are lost then. Check this page https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12679 , maybe you have some luck finding a solution there.