# Magento 2.3.2 Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list" component

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, onestepcheckout, magento2.3.2, component

I am using one-step checkout and getting an error in checkout console. and also page redirects to `/noroute/` `404` page.

> [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list" component.

I have checked in Magento 2.3.2 release note and see there is a change in the checkout, so I think it showing an error because of this.

so I just want to know how to resolve error **Failed to load component**

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 2.3.2 has made big changes in the checkout section. below is the link for changes commit in GitHub.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8a9a986f930cb5f8516b3fe5ecb6d1a6d3f9e8af

In my case, I need to override the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list.js` file in a custom module to resolve the issue.

**@Mike Dubs** you have to check above Magento changes commit to resolve your issue.

Comment: We had overriden billing-address.js, so I added list.js to a nested billing-address directory and it seemed to sort things out. Thanks @ChiragPatel

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 8):

Check your modules **requirejs-config.js**. Probably there is mapping like

`"Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": "Vendor_ModuleName/js/view/billing-address",`

Then later Requirejs try to load all files that have **Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address** from module where this file doesn't exists.

One option is to add to requirejs-config.js of the module extra line (instead of copying the list.js file to this module)

`"Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list": "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list",`

Ideally module should use mixins to modify **billing-address.js** to avoid this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this link maybe its the same thing.

[Magento Checkout Stuck: Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment" component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219842/magento-checkout-stuck-failed-to-load-the-magento-checkout-js-view-payment-co/256016)

Did you make any changes to checkout layout by yourself?

Comment: Yes i have changed in checkout step, and it is working fine in 2.3.1 but not working in 2.3.2 because of changes in Magento checkout release note.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Same issue here when upgrading to 2.3.2. Any resolution or tips?

Comment: Are you using one page checkout?

Comment: @Mike Dubs See my answer.